# Access SQL LEFT JOIN alternative

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join

I'm trying something in Access via SQL using a LEFT JOIN but it doesn't seem to be working. Access keeps generating the error "JOIN expression not supported.".

What I'm trying to accomplish is as follows. I have a table with job cards and another table with costs as below.

```
JOBCARDS
ID    JOBNAME
1     Job one
2     Job two
3     Job three

COSTS
ID    TYPE    COST    JOB
1     PART    15.01   1
2     LABOUR  20.00   1
3     LABOUR  40.00   2
4     PART    34.54   3
5     PART    84.67   3
```

I'm trying to formulate an SQL query that will give me the following result:

```
QUERY
ID    JOBNAME    PARTS    LABOUR
1     Job one    15.01    20.00
2     Job two    0.00     40.00
3     Job three  119.21   0.00
```

What I came up with:

```
SELECT
    CARDS.[ID] AS [ID],
    CARDS.[JOBNAME] AS [JOBNAME],
    SUM (COSTS1.[COST]) AS [PARTS],
    SUM (COSTS2.[COST]) AS [LABOUR]
FROM
    (([JOBCARDS] CARDS LEFT JOIN [COSTS] COSTS1 ON COSTS1.[JOB]=CARDS.[ID] AND COSTS1.[TYPE]='PART')
    LEFT JOIN [COSTS] COSTS2 ON COSTS2.[JOB]=CARDS.[ID] AND COSTS2.[TYPE]='LABOUR')
GROUP BY
    CARDS.[ID], CARDS.[JOBNAME];
```

Access seems to be having problems with the part "COSTS1.[TYPE]='PART'".

Is there any way I can accomplish what I'm trying to do without using a LEFT JOIN?
Or does anyone spot the error?

Comment: Correlated sub-queries.

Comment: I would join the 2 tables only on the job ID, and use an iif statement for the columns, something like  "Part cost:iif(type="part",cost,0)" and "Labour cost:iif(type="Labour",cost,0)"

Comment: try removing the brackets from `(([JOBCARDS] CARDS LEFT JOIN [COSTS] COSTS1 ON COSTS1.[JOB]=CARDS.[ID] AND COSTS1.[TYPE]='PART')  LEFT JOIN [COSTS] COSTS2 ON COSTS2.[JOB]=CARDS.[ID] AND COSTS2.[TYPE]='LABOUR')` Seems to me that the second join is outside the bracket context where the CARDS alias is declared? Maybe that's valid for Access but it doesn't look right to me

Comment: Hi ADyson. From what I've seen in Access it seems those brackets are required, otherwise the JOIN clause will not be accepted and an error will be generated.

Answer (score 3):

This SQL will give the result.
The 0 values will be Null, but you could use `NZ` to replace that with a 0.

```
SELECT      JobCards.ID
            ,JobName
            ,SUM(C2.Cost) AS Parts
            ,SUM(C1.Cost) AS Labour
FROM        (JobCards LEFT JOIN Costs C1 ON (JobCards.ID = C1.Job AND C1.Type = 'Labour'))
                      LEFT JOIN Costs C2 ON (JobCards.ID = C2.Job AND C2.Type = 'Part')
GROUP BY    JobCards.ID
            ,JobName
```

**Edit:**
Re-reading your SQL - you just forgot to put the brackets after the ON statements in your Join:
`(COSTS1.[JOB]=CARDS.[ID] AND COSTS1.[TYPE]='PART')`

```
SELECT
    CARDS.[ID] AS [ID],
    CARDS.[JOBNAME] AS [JOBNAME],
    SUM (COSTS1.[COST]) AS [PARTS],
    SUM (COSTS2.[COST]) AS [LABOUR]
FROM
    (([JOBCARDS] CARDS LEFT JOIN [COSTS] COSTS1 ON (COSTS1.[JOB]=CARDS.[ID] AND COSTS1.[TYPE]='PART'))
    LEFT JOIN [COSTS] COSTS2 ON (COSTS2.[JOB]=CARDS.[ID] AND COSTS2.[TYPE]='LABOUR'))
GROUP BY
    CARDS.[ID], CARDS.[JOBNAME];
```

**Edit 2**:  There's no need to put brackets around everything, or alias the field names if they're the same as the source field, or use the table names in the `SELECT` & `WHERE` clauses unless the field name appears in more than one table.

Comment: I feel really stupid now. I spent a few hours trying to get the query to work and it all comes down to me missing a few brackets!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a correlated sub-query example:

```
SELECT JOBCARDS.ID, 
       JOBCARDS.JOBNAME, 
       (SELECT SUM([COST]) FROM COSTS WHERE COSTS.JOB = JOBCARDS.ID AND COSTS.TYPE = 'PART') AS PARTS, 
       (SELECT SUM([COST]) FROM COSTS WHERE COSTS.JOB = JOBCARDS.ID AND COSTS.TYPE = 'LABOUR') AS LABOUR
FROM JOBCARDS;
```

Comment: Now I'm wondering which solution is the "best"? Using an IIF(), correlated sub-queries or my original idea?